# Как отправлять HTTP запросы методами PUT, DELETE, OPTION из обычной HTML формы в браузере?

Tags: php, html, http

Хочу разобраться с этими типами запросов. Пока что нашел решение для POST с _method="put" (PHP), не нравится так как в метод запроса POST а не PUT. Использование `<form method="put">` выдает GET,
а хотелось бы получить что-то подобное:

```
DELETE /users/123 HTTP/1.1
```

Как можно создавать запросы (ну или просто подготовить статические html-странички) с разными методами ? Может быть какой плагин или есть пример таких страничек или толковая статья по теме ?

Comment: [Why are there no PUT and DELETE methods on HTML forms?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms). Ну и возможные к использованию методы описаны в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission).

Comment: увы, не нашел ответа в статье. Я не спрашиваю "Есть-ли смысл использовать это"... Мне интересно как отправить запросы с данными методами.

Comment: Напрямую из HTML формы этого нельзя сделать, HTML формы поддерживают только методы GET и POST. Я Вам нигде и не писал про "смысл".

Comment: Ну а так, Ajax, скрытое поле описанное Вами выше, но оно будет работать не с любым бекендом это не есть чем-то универсальным, а скорее определенная конвеция.

Comment: Как вариант, используя [Fetch API JavaScript](https://fruntend.com/posts/primenenie-metodov-get-post-put-patch-delete-s-pomoshchyu-fetch-api)

Comment: Да, это подошло, проверил часть запросов. Тестовый ресурс отрабатывает только 5 штук, но и этого достаточно. Спасибо. Источник: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, из ссылок, которые вам дали в комментариях, уже все должно быть ясно.
На чистом HTML использовать любые методы кроме привычных GET и POST не получится. Я думаю потому, что у браузера просто нет визуальных средств отобразить эти запросы. Скажем, DELETE выглядит как тот же GET - это просто обращение по URI без тела запроса. Ну и как их отличить друг от друга? Ну или можно принять версию одного из авторов ответов по первой ссылке, что "просто никто не собрался написать спецификацию".

Поэтому отправить запрос одним из нестандартных методов можно только с использованием JavaScript. Например [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), которому в параметрах запроса можно указать метод.

Например, чтобы дернуть delete, достаточно вызвать

```
fetch('/goods/' + id, { method: 'DELETE' })
```

предварительно записав в id идентификатор удаляемого товара.

Если же говорить не про браузер, а про сервер, то в РНР эти запросы можно отправить обоими способами - либо через CURL, либо через file_get_contents